# Can I make the Gnome 3 overlay show the current wallpaper rather than the wallpaper on login?

Tags: gnome

I'm using Gnome 3 (`GNOME Shell 3.10.4`) and I have a script that changes the wallpaper using `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri <file>`. This works just fine with regards to the wallpaper itself, but whenever you open the overlay (click `Activities`/<kbd>Super</kbd>/hot corner) the wallpaper in the background is the wallpaper that was there when I logged in rather than the current one.

It's not a big deal I suppose, but it makes for a significantly more jarring change than it otherwise would be (especially as it changes on 3 monitors simultaneously). Is there any way I can set the wallpaper shown on this overlay or just notify it in some way that it has changed so it can invalidate whatever cache its using?

If it makes any difference, the script actually always sets the wallpaper to the same path (`/tmp/wallpaper.png`) just to make the shell re-read it as this is a temporary file that is really a combination of multiple other wallpapers that gets constructed on-the-fly.

Comment: Never noticed! That's gonna bug me until there is a fix now! And it does the same even when it isn't a temporary file. I'm using an app to change it.

Comment: Now this is very odd... just killed lightdm and restarted it, and now it is showing the current one. I wonder if something triggers it...

Comment: Well, my wallpaper is changed immediately upon login and it essentially never shows the same wallpaper in the overlay as it does on the desktop, so it seems to happen immediately. When you say it's showing the current one, is it updating appropriately or is did it just update once?

Comment: Updating appropriately... And mine changes at login too. But it wasn't working, I can confirm that...

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to give that a go tomorrow when I'm on that computer. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out I don't have `lightdm`, I'm using `gdm`, and restarting that (or full on `gnome-shell --replace`) doesn't seem to be working. :(

Comment: I am using `gnome-shell v3.12.2` on Arch Linux (with `gdm`) and after setting the background via the `gsettings` command given, the Activities overlay used the new wallpaper without any other action on my part. Tested twice with different wallpapers. Presumably this was a bug fixed in 3.12?

Comment: @muru No, I'm on 3.12 But I did see it briefly earlier. Edit: In fact, I have it now... https://imgur.com/pqXmcNd See the snake on my desktop and the snow leopard behind it... And I just used the command, and it didn't change the activities background. This must be a bug?

Comment: 'Alt'+'F2' and entering 'r' restarts the shell *(pretty much the same as `gnome-shell --replace` though)*, and may help with the issue. Do you specify the filename as `file:///PATH/TO/IMAGE`? I don't have this issue in 3.8 on Fedora...

Comment: Yes, the filename is specified as `file:///tmp/wallpaper.jpg`. Updating to `3.12` did kind of fix it, but it broke a hell of a lot of other things so I'm going to have to go through some pain to fix everything up before this becomes a priority again - I think I'm just going to change distro to Arch tbh as I've been thinking about trying that for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Easier than thought :

a) right-click with your mouse on your desktop then you find the location of where wallpapers can be set-into-your desktop

b) go to the directory of gnome for wallpapers and put there your favourite images into (usually in /etc/gnome or in /usr/share/gnome there is somewhere a directory for wallpapers + or you simply define an own script as *.lst - file for to allow certain images suiting to your profile of your user-in-your-mind only + ???? + )

c) back to desktop right-click on your desktop again and you pick then your over-lordian-image

;o)